# Make columns from np array elements

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got dataframe with shape `(35,1)`. Where elements of this dataframe are np.arrays length of `50`. I need to create dataframe `(35,50)`. How can I make it?

Tried `reshape(-1,1)`, but it's not suitable for this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df["col"].tolist(), index= df.index)
```

Comment: both the comment and the question are low quality, please provide clear examples and ensure formatting is correct to improve their usefulness

Comment: Sure, sorry dude, I'm fresh here. Reformatted the answer and the  question.